# Add if the record is not existing

Tags: sql, database, vba

I'm trying to create a program that will Import a spreadsheet and append/update it to my MainDB, 
I'm done with the Update Process, where if field(JobName) is found in to Main database, then I will update the record/s.
Next step is, to check if the record is existing, if not then I need a code to add that, Please help!

```
ConnectdbMain 'Sub Where I connect to my Maindb
Connectdbtemp 'Sub Where I connect to Tempdb which I imported to an excelfile
With rs
While Not .EOF
rst.MoveFirst
    While Not rst.EOF

    If .Fields(Combo.Value) = rst.Fields(Combo2.Value) Then   'the user is allowed which field is to compare and append I use combo box to filter choices.
    .Edit
    .Fields(Combo3.Value) = rst.Fields(Combo4.Value)
    .Update
    End If

    rst.MoveNext
     Wend
.MoveNext
Wend
End If

CloseDbMain
Set rst = Nothing
Dbs.Execute "DROP TABLE TempTable"   'I drop it like a trash since its already appended :)
ClosedbTemp
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I don't know about you. But if it's a excel spreadsheet I would use OLE DB to read the spreadsheet datasource and use SQL query to select all the DISTINCT JobName in the spreadsheet first.

And I would also use for in loop for every of the spreadsheet distinct name to execute a select statement in your main database with VBA to....

select count(JobName) from table where JobName = the_job_name_in_excel

Then use an If Then to detect if the returned row count = 0 then do an update statement.

Of course there's a lot more so you need to read on how to create a database connection to your main database and spreadsheet if you want to use my method. The methods in creating these connections is easily available out there.